# How to make this IF statement work

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, I'm trying to have the code run so people enter an amount of money and then it shows an estimate of how much they make daily. I want it to have an ERROR pop up if the textbox has no numbers in it. How should I do this?

This is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> MoneyPerYear </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="money.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p id="header"> Enter yearly income to estimate daily earnings </p>
    <input type="text" id="textmoney">
    <div onclick="moneyFunction()" id="moneydiv"> <p id="divtext">Calculate</p> </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>


    <script>
    function moneyFunction() {
        var money = document.getElementById('textmoney').value;
        var dailyE = money/365;

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (dailyE);
    }

    if ( document.getElementById('textmoney').value; == 0) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "ERROR";
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is all of it:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title> MoneyPerYear </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="money.css">
    </head>

   <body>
    <p id="header"> Enter yearly income to estimate daily earnings </p>
    <input type="text" id="textmoney">
    <button onclick="moneyFunction()" id="moneydiv"> <p id="divtext">Calculate</p> </button>
    <p id="demo"></p>


    <script>
    function moneyFunction() {

        var money = document.getElementById('textmoney').value;
            if ( document.getElementById('textmoney').value == 0) {
              alert("Error");
    }
        var dailyE = money/365;

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (dailyE);
    }


    </script>
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function moneyFunction() {
    var money = +(document.getElementById('textmoney').value) || 0; //parse required
    var dailyE = money / 365;
    //var result = money === 0 ? 'ERROR' : dailyE;
    var result = money === 0 ? 'ERROR' : parseFloat(dailyE).toFixed(3); //round-off
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result;
  } //closing bracket
```

```css
#moneydiv {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  background: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p id="header">Enter yearly income to estimate daily earnings</p>
<input type="text" id="textmoney">
<div onclick="moneyFunction()" id="moneydiv">
  <p id="divtext">Calculate</p>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```